# 戻り値を格納する方法を教えてください。

Tags: java

サブクラスのprotected int sum()以降をどう書けばいいかわかりません。配列要素の合計を表示出力したいです。

```
//スーパークラス
class SuperClass {
     public SuperClass(int[] array) {
        for (int value: array) {
            list.add(value);
        }
    }
    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
}

  protected int[] 〇〇() {
        int[] array = new int[list.size()];
        Object[] values = list.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (Integer)values[i];
        }
        return array;
    }
    public String execute() {
        String value = calculation();
        return "結果：" + value;
    }
 
}

//サブクラス
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
public SubClass (int[] array) {
        super(array);
    }
    @Override
    protected String calculation() {
        return String.valueOf(this.sum());
    }

　　
protected int sum() {
これ以降がわかりません。


＿＿＿

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
        Super myArray = new Subclass(num);
        String result = myArray.execute();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: calculate()等で値をStringを経由するのはそういう指定があったのですか？

Comment: ＠MNEMO 指示というか、テキスト通りに写しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`〇〇` メソッドで数値列が配列で取得できるので、これを [`IntStream` に変換](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D))して [`sum` メソッド](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum())で総和する

```java
    protected int sum() {
        return Arrays.stream(〇〇()).sum();
    }
```

と、所望の結果が得られるかと思います。
コンパイルエラーを補完すると、全体としては次のようになります:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//スーパークラス
abstract class SuperClass {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public SuperClass(int[] array) {
        for (int value : array) {
            list.add(value);
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    protected int[] 〇〇() {
        int[] array = new int[list.size()];
        Object[] values = list.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (Integer) values[i];
        }
        return array;
    }

    public String execute() {
        String value = calculation();
        return "結果：" + value;
    }

    protected abstract String calculation();

}
```

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

//サブクラス
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public SubClass(int[] array) {
        super(array);
    }

    @Override
    protected String calculation() {
        return String.valueOf(this.sum());
    }

    protected int sum() {
        return Arrays.stream(〇〇()).sum();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
        SuperClass myArray = new SubClass(num);
        String result = myArray.execute();
        System.out.println(result); // "結果：21"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

質問者が求めているのは、タイトルの「戻り値を格納する方法を教えてください」ではなく「配列要素の合計を表示出力したい」なのですから、それを実現する素直な(クラスの階層を作ったり、メソッドにアクセス制限(Protected等)を付けたりしない）プログラム例が回答になると考えました。

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // args は使ってません。
    int[] num = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }; // 合計を求める配列を用意する。
    int sum = 0; // 合計を入れるための変数を初期化( 0 にしておく）
    for (i=0; i <= num.len; i++) {
        sum = sum + num[i]; // 要素の値を合計に加えてゆく
    System.out.println(sum); // 配列要素の合計を表示する
}
```

Comment: SuperClassを継承したSubClassのprotected int sum() にSuperClassのprotected int[] 〇〇() 以降に注目して配列要素を取得をしないといけないので、、、